# Javascript hiding and showing divs on click on anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I seem to have messed up some very simple jQuery. I can go between divs 1 and 2 and from 2 to 3, but when I get to 3, I can't go back. It has to be some silly mistake but I can't see it?

```js
$('#show-form-stage-1').click(function(){
  $('#form-stage-1').show();
  $('#form-stage-2').hide();
  $('#form-stage-3').hide();
});
$('#show-form-stage-2').click(function(){
  $('#form-stage-1').hide();
  $('#form-stage-2').show();
  $('#form-stage-3').hide();
});
$('#show-form-stage-3').click(function(){
  $('#form-stage-1').hide();
  $('#form-stage-2').hide();
  $('#form-stage-3').show();
});
```

```css
#form-stage-2,
#form-stage-3 {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="form-stage-1">
  stage 1
  <br />
  <a href="#" id="show-form-stage-2">Next</a>
</div>
<div id="form-stage-2">
  stage 2
  <br />
  <a href="#" id="show-form-stage-1">Back</a>
  <a href="#" id="show-form-stage-3">Next</a>
</div>
<div id="form-stage-3">
  stage 3
  <br />
  <a href="#" id="show-form-stage-2">Back</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Try changing the IDs of the As to classes. Having duplicate IDs in a document can cause issues.

Comment: That did it! Many thanks David :-) If you want to post that comment as an answer then I can select it as the solution.

Comment: check jQuery toggle() method. It will solve your problems.

Comment: @Sam No worries, since it's been marked as a dupe I can't add an answer. Glad you got it working :)

Comment: The duplicate already says that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute [*id*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id) must be unique in a document. You have used same *id* (*show-form-stage-2*) for multiple elements. Change that to *class*:

```js
$('#show-form-stage-1').click(function(){
    $('#form-stage-1').show();
    $('#form-stage-2').hide();
    $('#form-stage-3').hide();
});
$('.show-form-stage-2').click(function(){
    $('#form-stage-1').hide();
    $('#form-stage-2').show();
    $('#form-stage-3').hide();
});
$('#show-form-stage-3').click(function(){
    $('#form-stage-1').hide();
    $('#form-stage-2').hide();
    $('#form-stage-3').show();
});
```

```css
#form-stage-2,
#form-stage-3 {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="form-stage-1">
    stage 1
    <br />
    <a href="#" class="show-form-stage-2">Next</a>
</div>
<div id="form-stage-2">
    stage 2
    <br />
    <a href="#" id="show-form-stage-1">Back</a>
    <a href="#" id="show-form-stage-3">Next</a>
</div>
<div id="form-stage-3">
    stage 3
    <br />
    <a href="#" class="show-form-stage-2">Back</a>
</div>
```

You can also achieve the same in a more simplified way by maintaining *class*:

```js
$('div > a').click(function(){
  $('div').hide();
  if ($(this).is(".next"))
    $(this).parent().next().show();
  else{
    $(this).parent().prev().show();
    $(this).parent().next().hide();
  }
});
```

```css
.form-stage{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    stage 1
    <br />
    <a href="#" class="next">Next</a>
</div>
<div class="form-stage">
    stage 2
    <br />
    <a href="#" class="back">Back</a>
    <a href="#" class="next">Next</a>
</div>
<div class="form-stage">
    stage 3
    <br />
    <a href="#" class="back">Back</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Give the unique id's to each element.

```js
$('#show-form-stage-1').click(function(){
    $('#form-stage-1').show();
    $('#form-stage-2').hide();
    $('#form-stage-3').hide();
});
$('#show-form-stage-2').click(function(){
    $('#form-stage-1').hide();
    $('#form-stage-2').show();
    $('#form-stage-3').hide();
});
$('#show-form-stage-3').click(function(){
    $('#form-stage-1').hide();
    $('#form-stage-2').hide();
    $('#form-stage-3').show();
});
$('#show-form-stage-4').click(function(){
    $('#form-stage-1').hide();
    $('#form-stage-2').show();
    $('#form-stage-3').hide();
});
```

```css
#form-stage-2,
#form-stage-3 {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="form-stage-1">
    stage 1
    <br />
    <a href="#" id="show-form-stage-2">Next</a>
</div>
<div id="form-stage-2">
    stage 2
    <br />
    <a href="#" id="show-form-stage-1">Back</a>
    <a href="#" id="show-form-stage-3">Next</a>
</div>
<div id="form-stage-3">
    stage 3
    <br />
    <a href="#" id="show-form-stage-4">Back</a>
</div>
```